# Не знаю, как быть с запятыми в ССП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Предложение небольшое, но от этого не менее проблематичное. Вроде как часть "и в наказание" не содержит сказуемого, отчего выделять её в качестве простого предложения, кажется, неуместно, однако верна ли моя догадка?

"Он хотел не рубить, а сжигать, и в наказание, мальчишка стал выгорать".

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните содержание или добавьте контекст (одно-два предложения), иначе смысл не очень ясен, так что знаки трудно проверить.

Answer (score 1):

***Он хотел не рубить, а сжигать – мальчишка, в наказание, стал выгорать.***

Это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение), вторая часть имеет значение следствия. Увеличенная пауза обозначается тире.

Обстоятельство "в наказание" обособляется для смыслового выделения в удобной для обособления позиции. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, обособлять «и в наказание» (как и «в наказание») нет никаких причин.

Разве что посчитать «в наказание» новым вводным словосочетанием :)

Comment: А смысл вам не нужен? Тогда и я попробую ответить, исходя из красоты графики. Заодно "вводное слово" обособлю, для чего нет никаких причин :)

Comment: «А смысл вам не нужен?» — а вам? «Тогда и я попробую ответить, исходя из красоты графики» — а красота графики вам не нужна? :) «Заодно "вводное слово" обособлю» — валяйте: я люблю абсурд :))

Comment: Абсурд? Неплохо название для профиля...  Моя графика хотя бы какой-то смысл выражает.  Автор хотел бы поставить там запятую, а почему? Вероятно, хочет выделить это слово (паузой). "Нет никаких причин"— удобная формулировка, я ее не однажды слышала. Да только  причина должна быть  в любом случае — и чтобы ставить, и чтобы не ставить.

Comment: «Да только причина должна быть в любом случае — и чтобы ставить, и чтобы не ставить» — :))) Сразу видно, что вы не юрист: юрист знал бы, что доказывать требуется НАЛИЧИЕ, а не отсутствие. Впрочем, можно аргументировать и в вашем стиле: приведите причины не ставить вот такие запятые (по причине на каждую запятую!): «Да, только, причина, должна, быть, в, любом, случае».

Comment: Легко. В простом предложении запятые на ставятся. А что оно простое - докажите сами.

Comment: Оно не простое — докажите, что это не так! :))

Comment: Я что угодно докажу, а что мне за это будет?

Comment: Сначала докажите, а то торговаться, ничего не предъявляя, каждый мошенник может :) Дано: предложение было простым, пока я в нём не понаставил запятых для смыслового выделения, а после этого оно стало сложным. Докажите, что не стало!

Comment: Простое сделать сложным? Это всегда пожалуйста. Когда я понаставил запятых в простом предложении и получил соответствующую оценку, у меня начались сложные отношения с родителями. На а если серьезно, то мне придется рассказывать вам структурные особенности простого предложения, а я не уверена, что вы готовы это слушать.